# SSL only listening when private IP is specified on AWS EC2 with Nginx, needs to be dynamic

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I've been banging my head trying to figure out the best way to go about this.  I have a EC2 AWS server that hosts multiple domains on a single server.

Let's say domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com

They are running with Nginx.  The issue is that in the host file for SSL they are all set like this where the Private IP address is set, I changed the IP to "1" for obvious reasons.

listen 111.11.11.111:443 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/privkey.pem;
}

My issue is that this is stuck on a private internal IP address.  I've tried to set it as:

listen *:443 ssl;

but it does not work and SSL fails.

My problem with this is that if for any reason this AWS server fails and we need to recreate a new one, all of the SSL certs will be stuck with the old private IP address.  I can see this being a huge issue.

How can I set this up so that the Private IP address can be dynamic such as *:442 or anything similar?

Comment: How about just `listen 443 ssl;`? If this does not work please provide any errors you get (see nginx error log) and the output of `netstat -nlpt | grep 443`.

Comment: *"but it does not work and SSL fails."*  These points need substantially more clarification.  *What exactly* does not work, and in what way do things fail?